# Test failing recognizing same element

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I have following piece of code which checks if the returned text is expected

```
console.log(typeof browser.getText('.modal.modal--primary.pin-container h1'));
expect(browser.getText('.modal.modal--primary.pin-container h1')).toContain("Enter PIN");
```

This returns

```
Enter PIN
F
```

And gives the following error

```
Expected [ true, true, true, true, true ] to be true.
running chrome
Error: Expected [ true, true, true, true, true ] to be true.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that there is more than one element which matches your selector. If that's the case, you'll get an array instead of a single value. You'll want to limit it to just one of them, with something like this:

```
expect(browser.getText('.modal.modal--primary.pin-container h1')[0]).toContain("Enter PIN");
```

Note the `[0]`.